# python: how to compute the sharpness features of image

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv

I am extracting the sharpness features of image as shown in the following image mentioned in a paper.

[image: sharpness]

I have done with the following code. 
Firstly, use the open cv convert the RGB to HSL (luminance is L  mentioned in the paper), then get L array.
and then used the Laplacian operator to get the LP. Finally, obtain the sharpness value of image based on mathematical form in the paper.

```
img_HLS = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
L = img_HLS[:, :, 1]
u = np.mean(L)
LP = cv2.Laplacian(L, cv2.CV_16S, ksize = 3)  
s = np.sum(LP/u)
```

I don't know my solution is right or wrong, if there is problem, please help me correct it. Thank!

Comment: That `gray_lap` should probably be `LP` (?)

Comment: yes you are right.gray_lap is LP

Answer (score 1):

What you have implemented is not what the formula denotes, but what you have implemented will return an indication of Sharpness, possibly with some minor modifications.

The formula produces a single $\mathbb{R}$eal number as the ratio of the local sum of laplacians divided by the local mean. "Local" here refers to a square image patch (of some dimensions) centred around pixel $(x,y)$.

If you forget about the division by $\mu$ for a minute, the $LP(x,y)$ is the sum of the "local" second derivatives. This is a $\mathbb{R}$eal number.

The way you have implemented it, the sum operates over the Laplacian of the whole image.

Furthermore, as the Laplacian is a $\mathbb{R}$eal number and the image is a $\mathbb{N}$atural (bounded) number (a.k.a a non-negative integer), you may experience rounding errors. I say "may" because the matrix used by opencv is also based on integers, so the rounding comes into play at [a different region](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html).

Evaluating the Laplacian over the whole image is not so much of a "problem" if that `sum` you used operates across both dimensions. Usually, in platforms such as GNU Octave, MATLAB and others, a single `sum` over some matrix, operates across **one** dimension (usually it sums the columns). Therefore, your `s` would become a *vector*...**not** a $\mathbb{R}$eal number.

Hope this helps.